# java.lang.NullPointerException: null, No puedo ingresar valores a una clase con arreglo de objetos

Tags: java

hola necesito ingresar estos valores de diferentes arraylist dentro de una clase para construir un servicio REST, pero no me permite utilizar arreglos de objetos para insertar dichos valores en mi clase por lo que no deseo estar declarando "n" instancias de mi clase para ingresar los datos:
Y OBTENGO EL SIGUIENTE ERROR

> (: Servlet.service() for servlet
>   [operations.ups.edu.ec.finalproject.config.JerseyCo nfig] in context
>   with path [] threw exception [java.lang.NullPointerException] with
>   root cause
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException: null
>           at operations.ups.edu.ec.finalproject.repository.imp.CoordinatesRepositoryValues.getCoordinates(CoordinatesRepositoryValues.java:32)
>   ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] )

aca mis clases

CLASE DE LA QUE DESEO GENERAR EL MICROSERVICIO

```
public class Coordinates {
    int pointId;
    String longitud;
    String latitud;
    double distanceKm;
    boolean statusCalc;

    public Coordinates(){}

    public int getPointId() {
        return pointId;
    }

    public String getLongitud() {
        return longitud;
    }

    public String getLatitud() {
        return latitud;
    }

    public double getDistanceKm() {
        return distanceKm;
    }

    public boolean isStatusCalc() {
        return statusCalc;
    }


    public static class Builder{
        Coordinates coordinates= new Coordinates();

        public Builder pointId(int val){
            this.coordinates.pointId= val;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder longitud (String val){
            this.coordinates.longitud= val;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder latitud (String val){
            this.coordinates.latitud= val;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder distanceKm  (double val){
            this.coordinates.distanceKm= val;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder statusCalc (boolean val){
            this.coordinates.statusCalc= val;
            return this;
        }

        public Coordinates build() {
            return this.coordinates;
        }
    }
}

CLASE DONDE SE SE ENCUENTRAN LOS VALORES QUE DESEO INSERTAR 


@Service
public class CoordinatesPointsValuesRepository {


    public List id(){
        List <Integer> id = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        id.add(1);
        id.add(2);
        id.add(3);
        id.add(4);

        return id;
    }
    public List Longitud(){
        List <String> longitud = new ArrayList<String>();
        longitud.add("234567");
        longitud.add("345678");
        longitud.add("6543");
        longitud.add("54322");

        return longitud;
    }

    public List Latitud(){
        List <String> latitud = new ArrayList<String>();
        latitud.add("234asdN");
        latitud.add("345678SE");
        latitud.add("65OE43");
        latitud.add("54NE322");

        return latitud;
    }
    public List distanceKm(){
        List <Double> distanceKm= new ArrayList<Double>();
        distanceKm.add(12.3);
        distanceKm.add(2.2);
        distanceKm.add(5.5);
        distanceKm.add(8.0);

        return distanceKm;
    }
}



CLASE QUE SE ENCARGA DE CARGAR LOS VALORES EN MI LA CLASE DE LA CUAL SE DESEA GENERAR EL MICROSERVICIO

package operations.ups.edu.ec.finalproject.repository.imp;

import operations.ups.edu.ec.finalproject.domain.Coordinates;
import operations.ups.edu.ec.finalproject.repository.CoordinatesRepository;
import operations.ups.edu.ec.finalproject.repository.maper.CoordinatesPointsValuesRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Repository
public class CoordinatesRepositoryValues implements CoordinatesRepository {

    Coordinates.Builder [] coordinatesBuild = new Coordinates.Builder[4];
    CoordinatesPointsValuesRepository coordinatesPointsValuesRepository = new CoordinatesPointsValuesRepository();

    @Autowired
    public CoordinatesRepositoryValues(){
    }

    @Override
    public List<Coordinates> getCoordinates () {
        List<Coordinates> setCoordinates = new ArrayList<Coordinates>();
        List<Integer>getPointID   = this.coordinatesPointsValuesRepository.id();
        List<String>getLatitud    = this.coordinatesPointsValuesRepository.Latitud();
        List<String>getLongitud   = this.coordinatesPointsValuesRepository.Longitud();
        List<Double>getDistanceKm = this.coordinatesPointsValuesRepository.distanceKm();


        for(int i=0 ; i <coordinatesBuild.length ; i++){
            coordinatesBuild[i].pointId(getPointID.get(i));
            coordinatesBuild[i].latitud(getLatitud.get(i));
            coordinatesBuild[i].longitud(getLongitud.get(i));
            coordinatesBuild[i].distanceKm(getDistanceKm.get(i));
            coordinatesBuild[i].statusCalc(true);
            setCoordinates.add(coordinatesBuild[i].build());
        }
        return setCoordinates;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los arrays solo instancian el objeto Array, no instancian cada instancia de los mismos, por lo que tú problema es que

```
 Coordinates.Builder [] coordinatesBuild = new Coordinates.Builder[4];
```

Nunca son instanciadas cada uno de sus elementos

Para hacerlo en esta iteración haz lo siguiente:

```
for(int i=0 ; i <coordinatesBuild.length ; i++){
        coordinatesBuild[i] = new Coordinates.Builder();
        coordinatesBuild[i].pointId(getPointID.get(i));
        coordinatesBuild[i].latitud(getLatitud.get(i));
        coordinatesBuild[i].longitud(getLongitud.get(i));
        coordinatesBuild[i].distanceKm(getDistanceKm.get(i));
        coordinatesBuild[i].statusCalc(true);
        setCoordinates.add(coordinatesBuild[i].build());
}
```